# Firewall on a VM

Tags: firewalls, virtualization

I know I could use a software firewall on the guest to achieve a situation similar to this, but is there a way to emulate a firewall (protecting multiple Guests) between a host and guests on a host-only VM network?

I've googled around, but haven't learned much - perhaps I'm using the wrong phrasing/vocab? I know this can't be a novel question.

Ps: part of the intent is avoiding configuring a firewall individually on each guest with the same settings so the guests stay

Comment: A host only network will create a virtual device on the host, can't you just use iptables to filter traffic to/from that?

Answer (score 6):

You can route the network through one guest which contains the firewall and then you just let all your other guests connect through the network of the firewall-VM.

Comment: This makes sense to me conceptually, thanks for the advice - I'll try to implement it tonight

Comment: [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/) is great for this, tiny footprint, vmware/iso/USB download formats, and enough features for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only familiar with a single offering at this time, but I'm almost positive there are more.  I believe the term most people are using is "Cloud firewall."

The virtual firewall that I'm familiar with is the 1000V ASA from Cisco.  See links below.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/quick_start/asa1000V/1000V_GSG.pdf
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/vpndevc/ps6032/ps6094/ps12233/data_sheet_c78-687960.pdf